# Adding a texture slow down my application

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, image-scaling

i use a `bufferedImage` to load textures inside my resource folder like this:

i use `ImageLoader` class to load images

```
...
public static final BufferedImage images = loadImages("/images/images.jpg");
 private static BufferedImage loadImages(String string) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(string));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
 }
```

*but when i add this to one of my objects like:*

```
 ...
graphic.drawImage(ImageLoader.images.getScaledInstance(200,200.java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), (int) objects.get(i).getX() - objects.get(i).getWidth() / 2, (int) objects.get(i).getY()
- objects.get(i).getHeight() / 2, objects.get(i).getWidth(),objects.get(i).getHeight(), null);
```

it slows down ***a lot my app*** , there is a way more efficent to load images, and more imporant,
***is there a way to prevent slowdown of the application?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list of the scaled images as field. And of course it would be nicer to use a variable:

```
// Field
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();

// Once, maybe in the constructor
... object = objects.get(i);
images.add(...);
```

Then in the painting method only

```
graphic.drawImage(images.get(i), ...);
```